# Xubuntu 16.04 usb display second screen / projector

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, multiple-monitors, display

**Specs**
Asus 102ba notebook - dual boot
Benq joybee gp2  - projector

I've just recently installed Xubuntu 16.04 on my notebook so far everything is up and working great. I'm just having some issues trying to get my laptop to display on my projector using USB streaming. I'm using a USB connection only between the projector and computer with no adapters. I'm not able to use a VGA or HDMI connection as my projector input pins are broken/bent for VGA/HDMI.

On Windows, when the projector is connected the driver automatically loads and displays the second screen. When I connect in Xubunutu, it recognizes another driver/CD has been mounted.

I'm still very new to Ubuntu I would prefer using it over Windows. Is there any driver or application I can run to help me get USB streaming work?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, your projector is USB compatible with Windows and Mac OS see page 23 of the user manual: 
ftp://downloads.benq.net/user_manuals/projectors/english/projector_um_user_manual_20120331_114457_gp2_en.pdf

There are no linux drivers listed on the downloads page: http://www2.benq.us/product/projector/joybeegp2/downloads/

The mini HDMI port (1.3) is not a part of the multi-input socket/wires (input 11) but is separate (input 12) per the user manual page 9.  There has been reported success with the HDMI input working with Ubuntu, thereby projecting to the projector, however, I did not discover any positive results for using this projector with Ubuntu or other distros via USB.

It may be possible to contact Benq for a replacement or repair of the projector pins or the multi-input wires/pins, though this model has been discontinued.  I wish you the best in your search and hope the mini-HDMI input is still an option, with or without an adapter.